# Angular routing not working for a link but working for all others

Tags: angularjs, routes

I got the routing working for all my links but one and don't understant what happens.

I include dependency to ui-router :

```
var app = angular.module('CMT', ['ui.router', 'angularCharts', 'uiSwitch']);
```

configure a new state :

```
app.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

$stateProvider.state('writeareview', {
        url: '/#/writeareview',
        templateUrl: 'partials/writeareview.html',
        controller: 'writeAReviewController'
    });
```

Declare the controller :

```
app.controller('writeAReviewController', ['$scope', function ($scope){
```

}]);

And my template is located in the folder "partials" with following code :

```
<div ng-controller="writeAReviewController"></div>
```

My link in index.html :

```
<li ng-class="getClass('/writeareview')"><a href="/#/writeareview">Donner un avis</a></li>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What’s the actual error message? Did you try using ui-router’s `ui-sref="writeareview"` directive instead of an `href` attribute?

Comment: No error message but problem solved by charlietfl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routing url shouldn't have a hash in it... that is done internally.

Change:

```
url: '/#/writeareview'
```

To

```
url: '/writeareview'
```

And change the href to only include hash with no leading `/`:

```
<a href="#/writeareview">
```

Or use

```
ui-sref="writeareview"
```

Also you will be invoking 2 instances of your controller when you include the controller in routing and in `ng-controller`. Remove the `ng-controller` duplicate